# Why won't my vertex buffer render in GLFW3?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, glfw

I have started to try to learn OpenGL, and I decided to use GLFW to assist in window creation. The problem is, since GLFW3 is so new, there are no tutorials on it or how to use it with modern OpenGL (3.3, specifically).

Using the GLFW3 tutorial found on the website, which uses older OpenGL rendering (`glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)`, `glVertex3f()`, and such), I can get a triangle to render to the screen. The problem is, using new OpenGL, I can't get the same triangle to render to the screen.

I am new to OpenGL, and GLFW3 is new to most people, so I may be completely missing something obvious, but here is my code:

```
static const GLuint g_vertex_buffer_data[] = 
{
-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW.");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
    if(!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create a GLFW window");
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if(err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW");
        fprintf(stderr, (char*)glewGetErrorString(err));
        return -1;
    }

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    GLuint programID = LoadShaders("SimpleVertexShader.glsl", "SimpleFragmentShader.glsl");

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(programID);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I know it is not my shaders, they are super simple and I've checked them against GLFW 2.7 so I know that they work. I'm assuming that I've missed something crucial to using the OpenGL context with GLFW3, so any help locating the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tested?  Did you add core profile, shaders, and VBO use all in one go?  Do it in steps, check each bit along the way.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend avoiding Core Profile.  It is not supported on many older-but-still-relevant graphics chips, not supported on some Linux drivers, is often more buggy than compat profile when it is available, and is only required on OSX (which doesn't support the 3.3 version you're using).  You're going to have an uphill battle with driver support if you use anything besides GL 2.1 + extensions (and only ones you outright need).  I doubt driver problems are your issue here, though; the simple cases all work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define your vertex data as `GLuint`s:

```
static const GLuint g_vertex_buffer_data[] =
```

However you bind this data as `GL_FLOAT`s:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

`-1.0f` when cast to `GLuint` and then interpreted as a `float` represents `NaN` (not a number) and lead to unspecified results, as the OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile specification states:

> The special values `Inf` and `Inf` encode values with magnitudes too large to be represented; the special value `NaN` encodes “Not A Number” values resulting
>   from undefined arithmetic operations such as `0/0`. Implementations are permitted,
>   but not required, to support `Inf`s and `NaN`s in their floating-point computations.
>   Any representable floating-point value is legal as input to a GL command that
>   requires floating-point data. The result of providing a value that is not a floating-
>   point number to such a command is unspecified, but must not lead to GL interrup-
>   tion or termination.

And since I don't see anything else obviously wrong with your code, changing `GLuint` to `GLfloat` should do the trick.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks, it's working perfectly now.